# "Cure of" vs. "cure from"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What's the difference between the following two?

> - God, cure me *of* this sickness that I have.
> - God, cure me *from* this sickness that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary says "To heal, restore to health (a sick person *of* a disease)". It does not mention "cure ... from", and none of its examples show this construction.

My intuition confirms this: if I encountered "cure ... from" I would think it a mistake, or archaic (though the OED seems to show that it did not even occur historically).

Comment: Merriam-Webster likewise has multiple "of" cases and no "from". You could cure someone from charitable principles, but this doesn't mean the same thing (from meaning *source, cause, agent, or basis*).

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference that I can see.

Answer (score -1):

'Cure of' is mostly used when cure is as a verb in the sentence.
 And "Cure from" is used when cure is as a noun in the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. If you had taken the introductory tour and read the help you would have seen that here we're looking for answers of sufficient length that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.