# "Die from cancer" vs. "die of cancer"

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

Is there a difference between those expressions: "Die from cancer" or "Die of cancer"?
Are they both correct?

Comment: I think you probably should have asked this on the site for [ell.SE].

Comment: @J.R. Actually my first instinct was to agree with you, but thinking about it longer the difference between the two is not so clear cut. Perhaps for a doctor the answer seems obvious but why do we have these two different prepositions? What's the difference; if any?

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68630/cure-of-vs-cure-from and curiously enough, we have one answer saying there is no difference.

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/die_1?q=die  If you switch to AmE you get the same answer.

Answer (score 8):

*to die of* some direct cause - cancer

*to die from*  something indirect like drinking caustic soda or illness

You can also *die by*

Here is a good list

http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic7051.html

> To die of Aids, of bird flu, of hunger, of overeating, of a heart attack, of cancer, of pneumonia, of childbirth, of stress, of a broken heart, of sorrow, of love, of curiosity (figurative language only, I hope)...
>
> To die from car/road accidents, from desease, from illness, from stroke, from a wound, from smoking, from drinking, from sudden death, from a weapon, from injury, from war, from religion...
>
> To die by (through the means of) the sword, by suicide, by overdose, by a bullet...

Answer (score 2):

*Die of* is rather more frequent than *die from* in both the Corpus of Contemporary American English and the British National Corpus, and by a greater ratio in the latter. It would take a closer examination of the corpora to see if there was much difference in meaning between the two. My intuition is that there isn’t.

Comment: Both terms as pointed out by mplungjan exist; you can *die from drinking* but you shouldn't say someone *died of drinking*. But  with "die of cancer" and  "die from cancer" it's not so clear cut. Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: You can say someone _died of drink_, so perhaps _died of_ has to be followed by a noun. I would guess that _die of cancer_ and _die from cancer_ had the same meaning, but, as I said, only a thorough examination of the evidence could tell us for sure one way or another.