# What's the difference between "die from", "die by" and "die of"

Tags: differences

What's the difference between "died from", "died by" and "died of" in the following examples?

> died of an old age
>
> died by poison
>
> died from hypertension

Comment: [“Die from cancer” vs. “die of cancer”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126187/die-from-cancer-vs-die-of-cancer)

Comment: Use complete sentences in your question please.

Comment: I've never heard _died of an old age_, just _died of old age_.

Comment: _died by_ is usually followed by a gerund, e.g. _died by poisoning_.

Comment: But there are exceptions, such as _live by the sword, die by the sword_.